# Receive asynchronous events from a web application to a desktop application in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I want to build a simple web 2.0 collaborative website using asp.net MVC2 or Flash  and I want to  receive events from a web based interface to a desktop AIR application. For e.g, someone makes a comment on a blog post, I want that information to be passed on to a desktop air application showing that a new comment has been made. What would be a good technique to receive asynchronous events?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to set a timer that will request the XML from your webservice each XXXX miliseconds.
An optimization tip could be ask if there are new items to load before call the complete XML.

Answer (score 0):

Two flash applications on same machine can communicate via [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) (even in one is AIR-based). To listen for call, it must be connected using some name. Use two different names in AIR and Flex app (one is to listen, second to send to).

Comment: what about if the applications are on different machines.a web site is always hosted on a remote web server

Comment: This is to connect web interface (browser app) and AIR app on local machine.